# How to create a list of scales using functional programming in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, functional-programming

I'm adapting code I have C to Python. I would like to re-write this piece of my code using the functional paradigm in Python. My current code:

```
X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3]

res = [0] * 121

for i in range(1, 31):
  k = 0
  for _ in range(0, 4):
    res[i] += X[i + k]
    k = k + 30

print(res)
```

How can I make this more Pythonic? Here reproduce a necessary scale in my algorithm with the following output:

```
[0, 9, 12, 11, 12, 13, 7, 12, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 9, 9, 11, 10, 8, 12, 15, 9, 8, 15, 11, 11, 11, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Thanks,
EDMC.

Comment: What do you mean by "functional programming?" Typically, Pythonic code is imperative (with some constructs borrowed from the functional paradigm sprinkled about)

Comment: While you could follow the idea of functional programming in any language (without getting any benefits, if the language, like Python, was not designed for that), this code has no connection with the functional paradigm. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider re-thinking your code as it basically re-assigns the zero-filled list of the length of the input list.
That shall be the thing that, to my current understanding, protects your code from being re-written in functional style.
However, packed your loop into more compact form:

```
for j in range(30):
    for i in range(4):
        res[1 + j] += X[1 + i * 30 + j]
```

**UPD: After Re-Thinking This, Came up with the Following:**

Suggest dropping the leading `0` as it does not seemingly bear any meaningful data:

```
X.pop(0)
```

Then, construct `res` without those trailing `0`-s in functional style as desired:

```
res = [sum(X[_::30]) for _ in range(30)]
```

Trust that solves your task.